# Export PDF as HTML using Adobe X

Tags: html, pdf, adobe

I am trying to make a tool which runs on server and converts PDF to HTML. Adobe X Pro is able to export the PDF as HTML, but I am not sure if Adobe SDK provides similar functions. Also is it possible to run Adobe X Pro from command line (I am unable to get any info about this). Can you suggest whether any of them can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Acrobat can NOT legally be run on a server - it's a violation of the EULA.

If you wish to use Adobe tooling for the server, that would be the Adobe LiveCycle ES product family.  In this case, you would want PDFGenerator (which also does file format conversions out of PDF).